# How can I set my password in OpenLDAP?

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I have installed `OpenLDAP` in 192.168.0.2 (CentOS), and used `LDAP Admin` to copy `People` and `Group` form another `OpenLDAP server` (192.168.0.1),

[image: Screenshot showing LDAP Admin interface]

`People` in 192.168.0.1 has a password, but in 192.168.0.2, it does not have a password, then I try to set a password but it does not work,

[image: Screenshot of command-line with LDAP output]

What can I do？

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? Have you actually tried _logging in_ to the LDAP server with this password (i.e. `ldapsearch -D cn=lzhang...` or `ldapwhoami -D ...`)?

Answer (score 0):

You *did* set the password. Most likely the 'userPassword' field is present but hidden.

Note that you didn't enable any sort of authentication for the `ldapsearch` command (neither SASL nor even simple DN+password), so it is connecting to the server in anonymous mode.

Since the 'userPassword' field contains security-sensitive information (the password hash), it is natural that the server would hide it from anonymous queries. In fact it would be normal to hide this field from *everyone*, depending on the server's security policy.

Attribute visibility is configured in either `slapd.conf` (the 'access' parameter) or via LDAP under `cn=config` (the 'olcAccess' attribute). You can bypass these restrictions when connecting as the rootDN, exactly like in your ldappasswd command.

For example:

- Anonymous search – most likely to be limited:

  ```
  ldapsearch -x -b cn=lzhang,ou=People,dc=zwkj,dc=com
  ```
- Search as normal user – may see more information about yourself:

  ```
  ldapsearch -x -D cn=lzhang,ou=People,dc=zwkj,dc=com -w -b cn=lzhang,ou=People,dc=zwkj,dc=com
  ```
- Search as the manager (rootDN) – should see everything without restrictions:

  ```
  ldapsearch -x -D dc=zwkj,dc=com -w -b cn=lzhang,ou=People,dc=zwkj,dc=com
  ```
- Bypass LDAP and read directly from database – will see absolutely everything:

  ```
  slapcat -s cn=lzhang,ou=People,dc=zwkj,dc=com
  ```